# Accessing ui-router resolve objects in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a function returning some data from an API inside ui-router resolve, and would like to access that object in my controller.

**UI-Router:**

```
.state('base.home', {

    url:'/',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve:{

        testResolve: function($http) {

            var api = 'http://myapi.internet/posts';

            $http.get(api).then(function(res){ 

                console.log(res.data);      // data is there! 

                return(res.data);

            })
        }
    }
})
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope, $http, $state, testResolve){

    console.log(testResolve); // undefined :(

})
```

I have searched some similar topics which lead me to the solution above, but my object is still coming up `undefined` in my controller.

Comment: you need to `return $http.get(api)...`  your `$http` is returning the data to the resolve, but the resolve isn't returning anything.

Comment: oh duh! but how do you return from inside the scope of $http? i think I have to return a promise right?

Comment: `$http` is a promise.  just add `return` at the beginning of the call.

Comment: ah! yes, that solved it! thank you!!!